# Why does my if else statement fail when combined with the sample function in R

Tags: r, if-statement, random, conditional-statements

I have two vectors that can be of variable length. I want to constrain how I sample from one by using the length of the smaller one. In this case, `xy` is smaller so the first part should execute and the second should be ignored, but when I run the code I get an error:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :    cannot take a
>   sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE' In addition:
>   Warning message: In if (xx > xy) { :   the condition has length > 1
>   and only the first element will be used

```
  xy<-c(1:5)
  xx<-c(1:10)

  if(xx > xy){
    father<-xy;
    mother<-sample(xx,length(xy), replace = FALSE)
  } else {
    mother<-xx;
    father<-sample(xy,length(xx), replace = FALSE)
  }
```

The error makes sense on its own, if I run those lines with `sample` separately but I thought the `if else` coding should prevent that.

Comment: In `if(xx > xy)` you can use `if(length(xx) > length(xy))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if statement you need to use the lengths rather than the raw vectors:

```
if(length(xx) > length(xy)) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the if condition to,

```
 if(length(xx) > length(xy))
```